# Ajax Response is giving data success error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am new to Ajax and want toperform some database interaction using AJAX in JQUERY by linking to PHP script.

```
        $(function() {  
          $.ajax({

                type: "POST",

                url: "response.php",
                data: {name:"amol"},
                success: function (data) {
                if (data.Success) {
                    alert('Success! We have data.Success!');
                 } else {
                    alert('Error! We do not have data.Success!');
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert('Error: ' + textStatus);
            }          
             });

        });
```

My response.php file does not contain much. The code in it is:

```
        <?php
         echo "Hello";
         ?>
```

I want to use this code for database interaction. But when I run this much of code , I get output as 'Error!we dono have data.Success!

Also, I want to know ,How to output variables from the php script on succesful response?

Thanks in advance for help !!

Comment: you are outputting a string and not json containing a 'Success' key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
success: function(data) {
    alert('Success! We have data - Success!');
}
```

Will work as expected.

What you are doing is asking if you have a `data` object with a `Success` item with the line

```
if (data.Success) {
```

`data` is just a string so this evaluates to `false`.

The `success: function(data) {` part already only occurs if you have successfully returned data

You then can use the data by adding that data to a div, alert or whatever as

```
 success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

You are returning exactly what is expected as the `data` variable does not have a `Success` item - instead you are returning a string (think $string = "hello" - `data` = $string in effect!)

Comment: Thanks for your response but when I do alert(data) it gives output <div id="header"><h1></h1></div>. Dont know why. @Graham Ritchie

Comment: Do you have a variable anywhere else named 'data' - it could be picking that up - if not, just double check you haven't changed your response.php page inadvertently - whatever is on that page will get returned (if you have closed PHP tags and have that outside of PHP then it will get returned.

Comment: I changed the variable data to some random variable and deleted response.php But still same. why?

Comment: Now it works fine. You were right . "if (data.Success)" evaluates to false. Thanks for your help. Dont know why I was having errors before.

Comment: One more thing I would like to share is that problem was with the path of response.php When I used absolute path , it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

try this code...

```
$.post("response.php", {name:"anmol"},function(data){
alert(data);
});
```

in your above code this..

```
<?php
         echo "Hello";
         ?>
```

here you pass string so simply you can use..

if you want to pass array of value so you can use like this

```
<?php
$data=array(
"name":"anmol",
"age":"21",
);

echo json_encode($data);
         ?>

    $.post("response.php", {name:"anmol"},function(data){
var json = $.parseJSON(data);
    alert(json.name);
    alert(json.age);
    });
```

here you only get alert when the function is success, in fail of function you can not get any response

Answer (score 0):

This works (I just tested) with your JavaScript code:

```
<?php

$json_response = array();
$json_response['Success'] = true;

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json_response);

?>
```

The problem was that you weren't responding with a JSON object (which is a data-interchange format).

Comment: I recommend that you set the dataType option when using jQuery.ajax function ([http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)) to establish the expected format of the response data (for example, JSON).

Comment: Did you replace the content of response.php with this code? I just re-tested and I'm receiving the success alert. In the HTML script I just "copied and pasted" your Javascript code into <script>...</script> tags and included jquery.js in the header.

Comment: When I created new html file and implemented it, it works fine. But dont know why its getting problem in existing code.

Answer (score 0):

The first comment in your post is right, as well as Graham Ritchie's explanation; also, you should check the examples in [jQuery AJAX documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Additionally, you should consider `done` and `fail`, instead of `success` and `error`, as they are getting considered deprecated in newer versions of jQuery. They are only a little more advanced, but more powerful.

Here's a general example:

```
    $(function() {  
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "response.php",
        data: {name:"amol"}
      })
      .done(function(data) {
        // What you want to do in case of success 
        // 'data' is going to be what the URL gives you. i.e.: HTML, JSON
        // You could append the HTML to a DIV or use the JSON in some way
      })
      .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        // What you want to do in case of error
      });
    });
```

I recommend you to check [this tutorial](http://jqfundamentals.com/), especially the last chapter on AJAX and Deferred.

Answer (score -4):

if u are new to ajax . i suggest you start using this shit

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'response.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {name: 'amol'},
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        if (data.Success) {
                    alert('Success! We have data.Success!');
                 } else {
                    alert('Error! We do not have data.Success!');
                }
        console.log("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    });
```